# Dynamic JavaScript time counter

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm trying to make a dynamic time counter/timer in JavaScript.

Why dynamic? Well I would like to display days/hours/minutes/seconds if the time stamp is bigger enough to display days or hours and so on.

In case the timestamp is less than a day I would like that the script dynamically displays only the hours.

```
1D 0H 59M 59S
23H 59M 59S
59M 59S
59S
MESSAGE
```

Here is the code I try to make it work.

```
<center>
<script>
    var countDownDate = new Date("2017-11-17T20:10:30Z").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Seconds
        if (distance < 1000){
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Minutes
        if (distance < 60000){
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Hours
        if (distance < 3600000){
            var hours = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 1));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Days
        if(distance > 3600001){
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " $
        }

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = "You will be redirected now";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>

<p id="count1"></p>
</center>
```

I think that my problem is related with math confusion in milliseconds but I can't find out what is wrong.

Comment: [Edit] - the link you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These changes made it work for me:

```
      <center>
<script>

    var countDownDate = new Date("2017-11-17T21:30:30Z").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Seconds
        if (distance <= 60000) {
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Minutes
        else if (distance <= 3600000) {
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Hours
        else if (distance <= 86400000) {
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }
        // Days
        else if (distance > 86400000) {
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = "You will be redirected now";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>

<p id="count1"></p>
```

I changed the milliseconds accordingly, and in your days you had a "$" so i changed that.

I changed the date around and got the effect I think you were going for.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply :)
The "$" was the error that makes me post :)

The display result is the same "0h 0m 38s":
I would like to have just "38s" if there's no minutes left to count down.

Comment: I fixed it. changed if's to if else if.

Comment: also you should call each time part only once.

Comment: HEY HEY IT WORKS ;)
That's the right stuff ;)
Thank you :)

Comment: Make sure to change the best answer ;)

Comment: Right ;).
Thank you A LOT for your "time"-r LOL :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing this the absolute hardest way possible, and also reinventing the wheel. There are a lot of great references to built in javascript functions (like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)) that you should really take a look at.

If you're doing this as an intellectual exercise think about restructuring your code into something like this (obviously just psuedocode):

```
let dateHTML = "";
if (time1.seconds - time2.seconds > 0) {
    dateHTML = (time1.seconds - time2.seconds) + "s";
}
if (time1.minutes-time2.minutes > 0) {
    dateHTML = (time1.minutes-time2.minutes) + "m " + dateHTML;
}
//So on and so forth for the maximum interval you want to account for.
document.getElementById("count1").innerHTML = dateHTML;
```

You can probably get really clever with null operators, putting the time unit distances into an array to clean up the syntax and avoid doing calculations twice etc. but this should cut down on what you're doing significantly.

Do keep in mind that there are JS libraries built to do this exact sort of thing really well, so if you're working on a "real" project consider that.

Comment: Thanks for your advise but I think that the above code is too abstract for my knowledge of JS for now.
Yes you are right I need to keep learn JS in fact I'm really new to JS.

Comment: I'll try and break it down a bit more for you. An hour is always greater than a minute, which is always greater than a second, right? The difference between a "1s" string and a "1m 1s" string is "1m ". Instead of making the whole string for each type of time, build the string UP as the amount of time increases! Then you're making fewer variables and making things less confusing.

You can do this man!

Comment: The code I posted is a modification that I found on w3schools.com to be more specific here is the link to the original code:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp
I'm going to document myself and get back to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the whole script in working order in case somebody else need it:**

The whole script is meant to be reused multiply times in a single page by changing the ID in the $FD['id'] array variable and copy pasting the function that prints/echoing the function content.

*PHP FUNCTION INCLUDE FILE (count.php):*

```
<?php
// JS Date format
// 2017-11-14T12:00:00Z

function counter($FD){
$date=$FD['date'];
$id=$FD['id'];
$display_start_1=$FD['display_start_1'];
$display_start_2=$FD['display_start_2'];
$display_end=$FD['display_end'];

echo $counter=<<<a
<center>
<script>

var countDownDate$id = new Date("$date").getTime();
var x$id = setInterval(function () {
        var now$id = new Date().getTime();
        var distance$id = countDownDate$id - now$id;

        var days$id = Math.floor(distance$id / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours$id = Math.floor((distance$id % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes$id = Math.floor((distance$id % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds$id = Math.floor((distance$id % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Seconds
        if (distance$id <= 60000) {
                document.getElementById("count$id").innerHTML ="$display_start_1 " + seconds$id + "s " + " $display_start_2";
        }
        // Minutes
        else if (distance$id <= 3600000) {
                document.getElementById("count$id").innerHTML ="$display_start " + minutes$id + "m " + seconds$id + "s " + " $display_start_2";
        }
        // Hours
        else if (distance$id <= 86400000) {
                document.getElementById("count$id").innerHTML ="$display_start_1 " + hours$id + "h " + minutes$id + "m " + seconds$id + "s " + " $display_start_2";
        }
        // Days
        else if (distance$id > 86400000) {
                document.getElementById("count$id").innerHTML ="$display_start_1 " + days$id + "d " + hours$id + "h " + minutes$id + "m " + seconds$id + "s " + " $display_start_2";
        }
        if (distance$id < 0) {
                clearInterval(x$id);
                document.getElementById("count$id").innerHTML = "$display_end";
        }
}, 1000);
</script>
<p id="count$id"></p>
a;
}
?>
```

*PHP DISPLAY FILE (count_display.php):*

```
<?php
$now = time();
// Simulation of utc time (-1 hour +1 minute)
// By modifying the amount of seconds you set/define the amount of seconds that will counted down
$timestamp_new=$now-3600+10;
// Time formattig for JavaScript code
$date_new=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $timestamp_new);

// Include the function file once only
include'count.php';

// Define variables for the first counter
$FD1['date']="$date_new";
$FD1['id']='1';
$FD1['display_start_1']="Please wait for another:<br >";
$FD1['display_start_2']="<br />We are preparing your playground for you.";
$FD1['display_end']="Your Playground is ready at:<br /><a href='http://555.555.555.555'>Game server 01</a>";
counter($FD1);

// Define variables for the second counter 
$timestamp_new=$now-3600+15;
$date_new=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $timestamp_new);

// The second count down timer
$FD2['date']="$date_new";
$FD2['id']='2';
$FD2['display_start_1']="Please wait for another:<br >";
$FD2['display_start_2']="<br />We are preparing your playground for you.";
$FD2['display_end']="Your Playground is ready at:<br /><a href='http://100.100.100.100'>Game server 02</a>";
counter($FD2);

// And so on ....

?>
```

Hoping that this will save a lot of time to somebody else ;)
Have a great life (you who can and know how) ;)